# Show in asp a image from a csv file

Tags: asp.net, csv, asp-classic

I have completed my script, which displays my csv in tables.

But here is the thing: I want that table 4 displays my actual image from a link in the csv. Is this possible?

This is a sample of my script that displays my csv in order:

```
Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream 
    sRows = oInStream.readLine
    arrRows = Split(sRows,";")

    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(0) + "<br></div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(1) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(2) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(3) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(4) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(5) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(6) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    Response.write("</tr>")
Loop
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

And here is how the csv looks like:

```
test,test,test,http://google.com/image.jpg,test,test,test
```

Comment: It will be faster if you `Response.Write` each part separately without the concatenation. Also, use a `For...To..Next` loop.

Comment: How are you storing the image in the CSV file?

Comment: @Paul i store the img like a link in the csv , can u give me a example of the above code ? because it all works , the only thing i want is that arrRows4 shows me a image,now it shows me a clickable link

Comment: Did you try my answer? From your csv example, it's arrRows3 that contains the image. If it's not correct, just put the line containing the img tag in the correct position.

Comment: @krlzlx i have try it , but my code above works normal , only want to show arrRow 3 a img in the column..

Comment: @krlzlx now it works with no error , but no picture , its empty

Comment: At which position is your image in a line in your csv starting at 0?

Comment: it works , i try another image and it showed up , but the other not , dont know why

Comment: Maybe the url was not correct?

Comment: You tagged this as ASP Classic and ASP.NET, but they're completely different technologies. Which is it?

Comment: Can you validate the answer if it's working for you? @user3785784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this (if your image is the fourth element in a line):

```
<%
    Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream 
        sRows = oInStream.readLine
        arrRows = Split(sRows,";")
%>
    <tr>
        <td><div align='center'><%=arrRows(0)%></div></td>
        <td><div align='center'><%=arrRows(1)%></div></td>
        <td><div align='center'><%=arrRows(2)%></div></td>
        <td><div align='center'><img src='<%=arrRows(3)%>' alt='' /></div></td>
        <td><div align='center'><%=arrRows(4)%></div></td>
        <td><div align='center'><%=arrRows(5)%></div></td>
        <td><div align='center'><%=arrRows(6)%></div></td>
    </tr>

<% Loop %>
```

Other way:

```
Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream 
    sRows = oInStream.readLine
    arrRows = Split(sRows,";")

    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(0) + "<br></div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(1) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(2) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'><img src='" + arrRows(3) + "' alt='' /></div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(4) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(5) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    strText = "<td><div align='center'>" + arrRows(6) + "</div></td>"
    Response.write(strText)
    Response.write("</tr>")
Loop
```

Comment: that one doesnt work , i get many errors , the one i have works perfect but i only want arrRow 3 to show my image .. can you change it in my script >?

Answer (score 1):

As requested:

```
Dim oInStream, sRows, arrRows, c
Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream
    sRows = oInstream.ReadLine
    arrRows = Split(sRows, ";")
    Response.Write("<tr>")
    For c = 0 To UBound(arrRows, 1)
        If c <> 3 Then
            Response.Write("<td><div align=""center"">")
            Response.Write(arrRows(c))
            Response.Write("</div></td>")
        Else
            Response.Write("<img src=""")
            Response.Write(arrRows(c))
            Response.Write(""" alt=""An image"" />")
        End If
    Next 'c
    Response.Write("</tr>")
Loop
```

The above code writes directly into the Response Buffer which is sent back to the client. Preventing concatenations speeds things up, or to use the HTML version, as per krlzlx's post...

```
Dim oInStream, sRows, arrRows, c
Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream
    sRows = oInstream.ReadLine
    arrRows = Split(sRows, ";")%>
    <tr>
        <%For c = 0 To UBound(arrRows, 1)
            If c <> 3 Then%>
                <td><div align="center">
                    <%= arrRows(c) %>
                </div></td>
            <%Else%>
                <img src="<%= arrRows(c) %>" alt="An image" />
            <%End If
        Next 'c%>
    </tr>
<%Loop
```

You may like to include a constant to record the field that actually contains the image, so you can test against this.